# How do I achieve this table layout design?

Tags: android, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I want to design a table layout which is given in this pages

http://ashadegreener.co.uk/androidK/agenda.php

(Not the menus on the right side & the header with logout button)

Only the full table layout design which is given in the left side. This design is only for 10 inch Tablet not for other resolution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Very strange question actually, and what is the problem with it?

Comment: Hi dude..I am new to android and design and i have managed the Java coding part...But in design i am struggling quiet a bit...I am having problem with the borders and did you see the second link in that one column is bigger like that.....??

Comment: I think all you need to know here is what is `LineareLayout` is and how it works. You can find all info you need at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the answer

```
    <TableLayout         
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="*" 
         android:background="#FF909090">

        <TableRow  
            android:layout_margin="0.5dip">

            <TextView 
                android:text="Invoice Number"       
                android:background="#E7EFE7"        
                android:layout_margin="0.5dip"          
                android:padding="15dip"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/tIN" 
                android:text="9912326989"       
                android:background="#E7EFE7" 
                android:layout_margin="0.5dip"          
                android:padding="15dip" />

        </TableRow>

   </TableLayout>
```

I had forgotten to give the layout_margin for the Table row tag.